# login sucessfully after login click any link session destory in zend framework 1.12

Tags: zend-framework

I have login successfully in zend framework. After login when i click to any other page link then zend session destroy in some computer. it is not session destroy to all computer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably using file as storage for php session and you do not have write permission to the php session directory.

Comment: I have not store session in file. I am using zend auth.

Comment: I am using default zend session not storage in any file.